# Consecutive rows having more than 100 employees

Tags: sql, oracle

write a oracle sql query to get three or more consecutive ids having num of employees > 100. For example, in the below data, we need rows having ids - 5,6,7,8
Explanation: rows with id 5,6,7,8 are consecutive and have >100 total_employees. However id 10 or 12 is not selected even though total_employees > 100, because they are not consecutive.

Input Data

```
create table employee(id integer, enroll_date date, total_employees integer);


insert into employee values (1,to_date('01-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),10);
insert into employee values (2,to_date('02-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),109);
insert into employee values (3,to_date('03-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),150);
insert into employee values (4,to_date('04-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),99);
insert into employee values (5,to_date('05-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),145);
insert into employee values (6,to_date('06-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),1455);
insert into employee values (7,to_date('07-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),199);
insert into employee values (8,to_date('08-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),188);
insert into employee values (10,to_date('10-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),188);
insert into employee values (12,to_date('12-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),10);
insert into employee values (13,to_date('13-04-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'),200);
```

tried to attempt below to get consecutive groups and flag for employee count, however not figuring out to get desired results.

```
select id, enroll_date,total_employees,
        case when total_employees>100 then 1 else 0 end emp_flag,
        SUM(case when total_employees>100 then 1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp,
        id - row_number() over(order by id) as diff, -- group consecutive id's
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN total_employees > 100
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY enroll_date) as sal_rn,
        id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN total_employees > 100
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY enroll_date) AS sal_grp
from employee
;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the total_employees column?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: we need ids to be consecutive, at the same time total_employees > 100, hence we need total_employees to check if count is > 100

Comment: What does total_employees 10 mean for employee id 1? And 109 for employee id 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    -- eliminate rows by number of total employees and create groups (islands)
  3    (select b.*,
  4       row_number() over (order by id) - id grp
  5     from employee b
  6     where total_employees > 100
  7    ),
  8  temp2 as
  9    -- count number of members per group
 10    (select a.*,
 11       count(*) over (partition by grp) cnt
 12     from temp a
 13    )
 14  -- finally, extract rows that have 3 or more consecutive rows in the same group
 15  select id, enroll_date, total_employees
 16  from temp2
 17  where cnt >= 3
 18  order by id;

        ID ENROLL_DAT TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
---------- ---------- ---------------
         5 05-04-2023             145
         6 06-04-2023            1455
         7 07-04-2023             199
         8 08-04-2023             188

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employee
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY enroll_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( consecutive{2,} last_row )
  DEFINE
    consecutive AS  id + 1 = NEXT(id)
                AND total_employees > 100,
    last_row    AS  total_employees > 100
)
```

or, filtering for `total_employees` first (rather than during the pattern matching):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE total_employees > 100)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY enroll_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( consecutive{2,} last_row )
  DEFINE consecutive AS  id + 1 = NEXT(id)
)
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| ENROLL_DATE | ID | TOTAL_EMPLOYEES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-05 00:00:00 | 5 | 145 |
| 2023-04-06 00:00:00 | 6 | 1455 |
| 2023-04-07 00:00:00 | 7 | 199 |
| 2023-04-08 00:00:00 | 8 | 188 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l5nWFeZm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to solve this gaps and islands problem. Her is an approch using `lag()` and a window `count()`:

The logic is to compare each id to the value of the "previous" id, and count how many times it changed.

```
with cte as (
  select id, enroll_date, TOTAL_EMPLOYEES, lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_sal
  from employee
  where TOTAL_EMPLOYEES > 100
),
cte2 as (
  select id, enroll_date, TOTAL_EMPLOYEES, id - sum(case when id - PREV_SAL = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) as grp
  from cte
)
select id, enroll_date, TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
from cte2 t
where grp in (
  select grp
  from cte2
  group by grp 
  having count(1) >= 3
)
)
```

Result :

```
ID  ENROLL_DATE TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
5   05-APR-23   145
6   06-APR-23   1455
7   07-APR-23   199
8   08-APR-23   188
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xIwEm3I8)